# AsyncHTTPClient max_clients

Tags: tornado, libcurl, pycurl

I set the number of max AsyncHTTPClients in tornado as follows:

```
AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient",max_clients=2000)
```

As you can see I'm using the curl_httpclient. Assuming hardware can handle more clients would there be any other software limits within the OS (Linux in this case) or libcurl that would be in place. For example if i set the max_clients=10000 should this just work out of the box?

Also if i have a multiple processes running tornado that each use the AsyncHTTPClient will each process get max_clients or is the max_clients number shared across all processes?

### UPDATE

Ok so the documentation states that:

> If additional keyword arguments are given, they will be passed to the
>   constructor of each subclass instance created. The keyword argument
>   max_clients determines the maximum number of simultaneous fetch()
>   operations that can execute in parallel on each IOLoop. Additional
>   arguments may be supported depending on the implementation class in
>   use.

So because each process has its own IOLoop i guess that means that each process can use up to max_clients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably also need to [increase the file descriptor limit](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/). Curl may use up to 4x ([default of `CURLM_MAXCONNECTS`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLMOPT_MAXCONNECTS.html)) as many file descriptors as you have `max_clients` (in addition to the other file descriptors that may be needed by your process).

There may be other limits that are specific to your environment, the network, or the site(s) you're crawling.

Comment: what if max_clients=10, however there are 20 "fetch" calls to the IOLoop? will it return for only 10 of them?

Comment: The first 10 will start immediately. When one of those finishes, it will return and one of the others will start.